# Bind/Display the two different columns data together inside a Dropdown for a particluar Id in "Edit" mode of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have 4 columns in Telerik RadGrid 
1) Account Code (only column shown in "Edit" and "Add" mode - Dropdown)
2) Account Description
3) Amount
4) Remark

Below is the "Add" mode code I am using:

HTML code:

```
    <mastertableview ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" autogeneratecolumns="false" datakeynames="AccountCodeID" InsertItemDisplay="Top"
                        insertitempageindexaction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" ShowFooter="True" CommandItemDisplay="Top">                                   
                             <Columns> 
                                 <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn> 

                                 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAcCode" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID" runat="server"/> 
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AccountDescription" HeaderText="Description" UniqueName="AccountDescription" SortExpression="AccountDescription" InsertVisiblityMode="AlwaysHidden" ReadOnly="true" ></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn aggregate="SUM" DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" FooterText="Total : " UniqueName="Amount" SortExpression="Amount"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Remark" HeaderText="IFCA Remark" UniqueName="Remark" SortExpression="Remark">

                                 </telerik:GridBoundColumn>    

                                 <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>                                                                            
                          </Columns>
                          <EditFormSettings>
                           <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                          </EditFormSettings>
                          <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Add new record" RefreshText="Refresh"></CommandItemSettings>
</mastertableview>
```

C# code:

```
protected void RGGSTAcCode_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            string CompanyCode = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DropDownList list = item.FindControl("ddlAcCode") as DropDownList;
            list.DataTextField = "AccountDescription";
            list.DataValueField = "AccountCodeID";
            list.DataSource = GetAccCode(CompanyCode);
            list.DataBind();
            list.Items.Insert(0, "- Select -");
        }       
    }

protected void RGGSTAcCode_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

        DropDownList accountCode = item.FindControl("ddlAcCode") as DropDownList;
        string SelectedAccCode = accountCode.SelectedItem.Text;

        //split dropdown 2 vales
        string accCode = SelectedAccCode.Substring(0, SelectedAccCode.IndexOf('-')).Trim(); //getting a/c code
        string accDesc = SelectedAccCode.Substring(SelectedAccCode.IndexOf('-') + 1).Trim(); //getting a/c descr

        InsertAccountCode(new Guid(TempGUID.Text), accCode, accDesc);
        BindGrid();
        RGGSTAcCode.Rebind();
    }
```

"Account code" column is only shown in "Add" and "Edit" mode of RadGrid. It is a Dropdown in which I have to bind the 2 values together i.e., Account code + Account Description, and have to show and save it in separate columns of Database. (i.e, Account Code value in Account code column and Account Description value in Description column)

**Now my requirement is that:** While doing "Edit", I want to bind/display the "Account code" column data and "Account Description" column data together inside Dropdown, which is saved in Database for a particular ID. Just like we bind dropdown while Edit.

and later after Editing the Dropdown item, data will be saved to two different columns of DB as I am doing while Adding the records.

Only I am not getting how to display/bind the two different columns data together inside a Dropdown when doing "Edit".
Please suggest some solution.

I hope I am able to make my requirement clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please someone help me in this requirement. I am trying from my end too but still no luck. I know its a simple requirement but I am unable to do it using RadGrid as I have no experience working with Telerik RadGrid. Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. Clear your thoughts about this issue.

What type of **databind** you are using **?** whether advanced databind / sqldatasource databind?

Anyway you have four columns in your grid right! so change your select query like below one.

`SELECT accountcode, accountdesc, amount, remark, convert(varchar(20),accountcode)+' '+accountdesc as accdetail FROM YOURTABLENAME`
 **<--**  Note down that accdetails.

I'm concatanating the fields  `accountcode` and `accountdesc` as **accdetail** (**with a empty space** ).
So now your grid has 5 rows. **Hide** the fifth row in the gridview using `Visible="false"` in that accdetail column.
Don't modify the accountcode column.
Do the change only in Dropdownlist.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccdetail" DataTextField="accdetail" DataValueField="accdetail" runat="server"/>
```

Now the dropdown will show the content as `accountcode accountdesc` in editmode.

On **Insert**, do the following code change

```html
protected void RGGSTAcCode_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
  GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
  DropDownList ddlAccdetail = item.FindControl("ddlAccdetail") as DropDownList;
  
  string Accdetail = ddlAccdetail.SelectedItem.Text;
  string accCode=Accdetail.Split(' ')[0];   //Splitting the string 
  string accDesc=Accdetail.Split(' ')[1];   //with that added empty space

  InsertAccountCode(new Guid(TempGUID.Text), accCode, accDesc);
  BindGrid();
  RGGSTAcCode.Rebind();
}
```

Thats it, hope it will work. But keep it in mind if you have any empty space in your `accountcode` or `accountdesc` field by default, then you need to change that **Empty space** to any special character like **( - , * , / ,)**

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am binding Dropdown using Stored Procedure. Here is my SP query: SELECT [AccountCodeID] ,[AccountCode]+' - '+[AccountDescription] as [AccountDescription]     
FROM [tbl_AccountCode] order by [AccountCode]+' - '+[AccountDescription] . Since the 2 values are saved in DB in 2 different columns, only while bind I show them together inside Dropdown and save it using Split function. 
Now, during "Edit" I want to bind same record inside Dropdown which is saved in 2 different column of Database, for the particular ID ?

Comment: Where shall I write your query for "Edit", under which event ?

Comment: Also, the changes you are telling to do in HTML Dropdown code is already there in my code. "Add" functionality is already done. I am facing problem in Edit while binding the dropdown value related to particular Id. 
Right now when I click on Edit, it shows the 1st value of Dropdown for all Id's but not the value related to particular Id.